# Определение наследуемого класса Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть некий кошелек, в котором пока что есть только монетки и ключи для сундуков. На данный момент player выглядит вот так:

```
private Wallet _wallet;

public event UnityAction<int> CoinsCountChanged;
public event UnityAction<int> KeysCountChanged;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Resource>(out Resource resource))
    {
         if (resource is Coin)
         {
              _wallet.AddCoin((Coin)resource);
              CoinsCountChanged?.Invoke(_wallet.Coins);
         }
         else if (resource is Key)
         {
              _wallet.AddKey((Key)resource);
              KeysCountChanged?.Invoke(_wallet.Keys);
         }
 
         Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Key и Coin наследуются от Resource,
и сам кошелек, который имеет 2 свойства и 2 метода добавления каждого из ресурсов.
Если бы я хотел иметь много ресурсов, например разные типы кристаллов, монет и ключей, мне бы пришлось для каждого ресурса писать свой иф, создавать событие под него и метод в кошельке. Тогда OnTriggerEnter превратился бы в сплошной копипаст.
Есть идея закинуть эту проверку в кошелек, но тогда его нужно будет делать пабликом, что бы подписаться на событие для вывода. Да и не совсем логично когда ресурс определяет кошелек а не плеер.
Есть более логичная, но и затратная идея, передавать в кошелек Resource, а в кошельке создать и перегрузить метод на разные типы ресурсов. Но опять же вопрос, как определить что это за ресурс?
Может есть идея как это реализовать лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public enum ResourseTypes { Gold, Key, Wood, Rock }

// вешаем на игрока
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class ResourseStash : MonoBehaviour {

    public event Action<ResourseTypes, int> ResourseAddes;
    public event Action<ResourseTypes, int> ResourseSpended;
    public event Action<ResourseTypes, int> ResourseChanged;

    private Dictionary<ResourseTypes, int> _resourses;

    private void Awake () {
        _resourses = new Dictionary<ResourseTypes, int>();
    }

    public int Count (ResourseTypes type) {
        return _resourses.ContainsKey(type) ? _resourses[type] : 0;
    }

    public void AddResourse (ResourseTypes type, int count) {
        if (_resourses.ContainsKey(type) == false)
            _resourses.Add(type, 0);
        _resourses[type] += count;
        if (ResourseAddes != null)
            ResourseAddes.Invoke(type, count);
        if (ResourseChanged != null)
            ResourseChanged.Invoke(type, _resourses[type]);
    }

    public bool TrySpendResourse (ResourseTypes type, int count) {
        if (_resourses.ContainsKey(type) != false && _resourses[type] >= count) {
            _resourses[type] -= count;
            if (ResourseSpended != null)
                ResourseSpended.Invoke(type, count);
            if (ResourseChanged != null)
                ResourseChanged.Invoke(type, _resourses[type]);
            return true;
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Does not have "+count+" "+type.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
public class CollectableResourse : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private ResourseTypes _type;
    [SerializeField] private int _count;

    // ресурс сам подберётся столкнувшись с носителем ресурсов
    // или можно прописать в ResourseStash, на вкус
    private void OnCollisionEnter (Collider2D collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<ResourseStash>(out ResourseStash stash)) {
            stash.AddResourse(_type, _count);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Отличный код, возьму кусочек.
Куда впихнуть энам, если он нужен в 3х местах например?

Comment: Не правильно задал вопрос.. Как текстом взять тип моего ресурса? Не хотелось бы создавать поле с названием. Есть способ взять имя класса, или не стоит и лучше сделать по другому?

Comment: В любом случае нет смысла отвечать на то, как одевать штаны через голову. Исправил spend, ошибка и зарефакторил. А если собиратерь ресуросов 1, то и это не имеет смысла, класс должен быть не компонентом, а singleton.

Comment: Собиратель ресурсов это плеер. Я к тому, что использовать глобальную переменную не хорошо. Поэтому хотелось бы брать тип ресурса навешенный на него. С этим проблем нет, но если передавать в UI просто тип и кол во, нужно понимать куда записывать. И тут нужно либо знать все типы ресурсов наследуемых от Resource, либо каждому бару записать тип ресурса, который он будет принимать и делать проверку.